# Wordpress query operator not work at all

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a list of categories : Best Products > Products List.
I wrote this query to get all best products if user check to Best products.I made all products just checked in Products List but my homepage still display them all.What's wrong here?
Tks for your rep :)

```
      <div class="col-xs-12 clear products">
          <div class="col-xs-12 clear responsive-bp">
          <?php 
          $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('products'), 
            'tax_query' => array(
                 'relation' => 'AND',
                 array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'products-category', 
                    'field'     => 'slug', 
                    'terms'     => array('best-products'), 
                    'operator'  => 'IN', 
                ),
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => 6, 
          );

          // WP_Query
          $eq_query = new WP_Query( $args );
          if ($eq_query->have_posts()) : // The Loop
          ?>
          <?php 
          while ($eq_query->have_posts()): $eq_query->the_post();
          ?>
            <div class="item-np col-xs-12">
              <a class="fl pro-img" title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><span class="marked-img"></span><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail('medium');}?></a>
              <a class="clear col-xs-12 pro-tit" title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title() ;?></a>
              <span class="clear col-xs-12 pro-type"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">View</a></span>
              <p class="clear col-xs-12 pro-price">
                <span><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcf-product-price', true ); ?></span> <span><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'weight-product', true ); ?></span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> 
            <?php endif; ?> 
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work for you:

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('products'), 
        'tax_query' => array(
             array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'products-category', 
                'field'     => 'slug', 
                'terms'     => 'best-products', 
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 6, 
      );
```

Comment: It should've worked. Please see this doc for details.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Is there any other taxonomy term you've created or there is only "Best Products" term. If that is the only term then any product you add will go to Best Products by default.

Comment: Ofcourse i create many taxonomy term but best products is the top parent of all taxonomy term